# Get Link to open in Chrome from Electron application

Tags: angular, hyperlink, electron, href, anchor

I currently have an angular application running fine in the browser as well as the desktop app on my mac. However all the links when running from the desktop app open a new window that is not my default browser (chrome). I would like all of the links to open in chrome (preferrably using the already opened instance of chrome if available) All of the `<a>` in my application are using `target="_blank"`. I found this method that i tried in my main.js file

```
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
    console.log(url);
    shell.openExternal(url);
    return { action: 'allow' };
  });
```

and in my app.component.html I simply have this as a test:

```
<a href="https://google.com target="_blank">Google Link Test</a>
```

and yet when i click this link when running from electron my screen turns red, the app crashes, and im greeted with this in my console:

```
https://google.com
MY_PATH/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron exited with signal SIGSEGV
```

What am i doing wrong that is causing an exception to crash my application?

Answer (score 0):

All I was missing was:

```
const shell = require('electron').shell;
```

at the top of my file.